# Generate array from type without infering

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I need to generate real JS code based on TS type, so I can prevent doubling code and creating the chaos.

```
export interface TypesInfo {
    mysqlDatabases:    "db1" | "db2" | "db9";
}

//

export class Service {
    protected static $SetInfo() {
        return {
/*instead of true, it has to be TypesInfo.mysqlDatabases converted to array, so ["db1", "db2", "db9"];*/
            mysql: true, // ["db1", "db2", "db9"] instead of true
            mongodb: true
        };
    }
}
```

Infering the type from array won't work for me, because you can't put array inside interface, because interface isn't runtime.

Basically `TypesInfo.mysqlDatabase` type should also works as enabler, not only for type checking.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w11X8w), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing (with no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values). This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: It is impossible to use interfaces at runtime, so if you want to do this at all, you *must* infer the type from an array.  You can indeed refactor to do this, and I'd be happy to show you what I mean if you'd do the courtesy of providing a standalone code example without undeclared types or values.  It will look something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK8J8w), assuming your example can survive with those undeclared types/values simply removed.

Comment: @jcalz i did what u asked for :)

Comment: So, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqvnQW) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, can you explain why?  (e.g., don't just say "I can't do this", you should explain how it fails to meet your use case)

Comment: Is it just coincidental that your `Service` generic type parameter is the same name as your interface (`TypesInfo`)? Also, you aren't using that generic type parameter. I.e., what are you expecting to get out of adding `<TypesInfo>` to `Service`?

Comment: @jcalz unfortunatelly not, its third unit that describes Service program. It has to be sticked to only two. I have interface `TypesInfo` so user should expect all types info in there, but using `infering type` like u did makes a surprise, there are another type infos outside of type infos, it would be terrible design.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2Ky4N) seem better to you? It's two things again instead of three, but there's not much difference between them. In any case I'm a bit hesitant to continue to engage; saying "it would be terrible design" is either an exaggeration or you have excessively strict standards which are unlikely to be met by any additional effort. I suggest you edit the text of the question to list out your actual requirements (e.g., "there can only be two things, not three"), but be prepared for the problem to have no solution due to overconstraint.

Comment: @jcalz: I must say it surprised me a lot, very interesting method. It's the closest to my needs. Please make an answer and I'll accept that. Thanks You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to avoid the redundancy of specifying both the  array value `mysql` and the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of its element types `mysqlDatabases`, so you've asked for a way to generate the array value from the union type.

Unfortunately, this is not possible; the `TypesInfo` interface, like all interfaces, is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript, and so there will be nothing from which to build the array you want.  You can't generate JavaScript values from TypeScript types.

You can do things the other way, though.  So the only possible way to avoid redundancy here is to generate the TypeScript type `"db1" | "db2" | "db9"` from the JavaScript value `["db1", "db2", "db9"]`.

---

If your `Service.$SetInfo()` static method were `public` instead of `protected`, then the least redundant way of doing this would be to define the array explicitly in the return value's `mysql` property:

```
export class Service {
    static $SetInfo() {
        return {
            mysql: ["db1", "db2", "db9"] as const,
            mongodb: true
        };
    }
}
```

and here (as in all such solutions) we are using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to ask the compiler to remember the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of its elements.

Then, you could define `TypesInfo`'s `mysqlDatabases` property in terms of the `$SetInfo` method:

```
export interface TypesInfo {
    mysqlDatabases: ReturnType<typeof Service.$SetInfo>['mysql'][number];
    // (property) AllPublic.TypesInfo.mysqlDatabases: "db1" | "db2" | "db9"
}
```

This works, but it exposes `Service.$SetInfo` to external consumers.

---

If you'd like to keep `Service.$SetInfo` as a `protected` method and you don't want to expose anything else, then I think the only reasonable way to proceed is to define the array inside your module without exporting it, and then define both `TypesInfo` and `$SetInfo` in terms of this module-private value:

```
const mysqlDatabases = ["db1", "db2", "db9"] as const;

export interface TypesInfo {
    mysqlDatabases: typeof mysqlDatabases[number];
}

export class Service {
    protected static $SetInfo() {
        return {
            mysql: mysqlDatabases,
            mongodb: true
        };
    }
}
```

This does add another declaration inside your module, and in the comments you've made it clear that this is unacceptable.  But I want to present it because it is very similar to your original code in terms of package scoping.

---

A middle ground which you may accept is to publicly expose just the array instead of the entire `$SetInfo` method, by making the array a separate static property of `Service`:

```
export class Service {
    static mysqlDatabases = ["db1", "db2", "db9"] as const;
    protected static $SetInfo() {
        return {
            mysql: Service.mysqlDatabases,
            mongodb: true
        };
    }
}

export interface TypesInfo {
    mysqlDatabases: typeof Service.mysqlDatabases[number];
}
```

Personally I prefer the three-declaration solution to this, because there seems to be no good reason to expose `mySqlDatabases` array to external users of `Service`, but if you really value having only two declarations in the module, then this might be a good compromise.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBANmgCgVwEZoEt4kBvAKCUqQgA8YB7AJwBckDhmJGAzBZAFQCeMaAElg3eqQpVZYQVACOaACIhmIXCCjQAXEgBKEZtkbAhIgDzNhEetyQBlLgDciEAHQASZ83GSAPgBtAHJ5JTQQgF0g4GwwXC4ogG4ZWUoAegykAAoYRnoRFkEASlQMHHwiDwsxCXoPcOU1DS0dKH0AIgATXABGTqQAHyQe3AAmQZGxgE5OtKQAXzIF2gYWJHg0bSgnV3dpdKooDWYiJB9jf3ocsvIjo8ZjU2BDh-emtH0gsYGAGlGvUmANmnSiSG0m3owBOfwW7zk0IA5vRevpmIxsBB4Q9Fql3stZMtlmRQJBYHwkAA5ejMSqEeAAIWwzH4AAsCIxuuz2EjpAt4NCTkhPi1NNpoEgALxIH69f6AiadEG9ObgyGCmHMVKrOhMVjsTg8Sm1KDXN5HUXqcXtdG2ewihTNa1taCxeKJRgpBYk2RrfWbbZQXbORhuRAW9L5WkQeCcbpIE7qc6XPz1W6R95PExmTMIyiffRW1oSqBw-OW5Go3DozHYitLfG4n0rMgksnQOARgDywAg9KIAFEaBiQDzgEjMAgANYgJEQbriZj0UPh5DkXXrA0cLi8COm833B7Fm16JA2EQO1fuRpO1Qu0vuhJJJuUX1Uf0bLY7PZhg5Ho4kzOYgT1dXYZTlfplUVYFFTVCFdk1E5XyjApODjBdE1OFNfGuDMAIRbMXjzfNC1-NdbwiMUwPLBsqDAKs0XPOscSOPFWKWFs2yAA)

Answer (score 1):

> Infering the type from array won't work for me, because you can't put array inside interface, because interface isn't runtime.

Instead of using `mysqlDatabases: "db1" | "db2" | "db9";`, you could create an enum, which is available at runtime.

```
export interface TypesInfo extends BaseServiceTypesInfo {
    mysqlDatabases: YourTypeEnum ;
}

enum YourTypeEnum {
    db1 = "db1",
    db2 = "db2",
    db9 = "db9",
}
...
mysql = Object.values(YourTypeEnum);
```

Comment: Yes, but it still third type/unit in code, it has to be only interface TypesInfo and class Service

Comment: "it has to be only interface TypesInfo and class Service"; why? that's not in the question. What breaks if you do it this way?

Comment: It's about chaos/mess in code, engine should allow to create Service like programs, in simplest way. You have your "TypesInfo" interface and your first guest is ok here I have all types info of service, but surprise, there is some type info outside of it! yak!

Comment: @ElSajko I've looked at a lot of TypeScript code and the addition of a single extra type or variable to enforce a constraint is not anywhere near "chaos/mess".  Have you seen [the TypeScript standard library declaration files](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/534fc14c662cc49c1c71f3830b32f98ff7472e87/lib)? They are full of interface definitions that point to definitions outside themselves.